# Unwanted Type mismatch error in Generic Inheritance

Tags: java

Following code is not getting compiled and is giving below error upon compilation error at `line 1`:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from fourLegged to Dog1

From my understanding it should get compiled successfully and should not give any error.

```
   public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyAnimal obj = new MyAnimal();
        Dog1 carDoor = obj.get()//Line 1;
    }

}

class MyAnimal<C extends BlackDog> extends AbstractAnimal<C> implements Animal1 {

}

abstract class AbstractAnimal<C extends FourLegged> {

    public C get() {
        return null;
    }

}

interface Animal1 {
    public Dog1 get();
}

interface FourLegged {
}

interface Dog1 extends FourLegged {
}

interface BlackDog extends Dog1 {
}
```

Can some one help me understand this behavior.

Comment: Side note: if you'd stick to the Java code conventions (which are there for a reason) it would be `FourLegged`. Also mind your naming in general, `MyAnimal` and `myCar` don't seem to fit very well and doing this on a larger scale might introduce hard to find bugs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: @Tom- It is not duplicate please check again

Comment: It is. You're using a raw type and you already implicitly said (with your *"But why it is disabling generic type checking ?"* comment) that you don't know what a raw type is and what it causes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `MyAnimal myCar = new MyAnimal();` basically disables generic type checking and hence the code only knows that what `get()` returns is a `FourLegged`.

Changing it to `MyAnimal<BlackDog> myCar = new MyAnimal<>();` (or even `MyAnimal<?> myCar ...`, see Seelenvirtuose's comment)  should make it work. In both cases the compiler will then know that `C` in `get()` is (at least) an instance of `BlackDog`.

Comment: @Thoms- Thanks a lot. But why it is disabling generic type checking ?